# Failed to migrate: buildpacks from Heroku to Nixpacks

Tags: javascript

Failed to migrate: buildpacks from Heroku to Nixpacks

I need help I can't do the migration of my front end projects it doesn't compile and gives an error.

My Heroku buildpacks:

This script works correctly to generate the application on Heroku and Vercel, but I can't install it with the Nixpacks package. Can someone tell me what is wrong with the scripts?

"scripts": {

"dev": "react-scripts start",

"start": "serve -s build",

"build": "react-scripts build",

"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",

"eject": "react-scripts eject",

"heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",

"install:clean": "rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf package-lock.json && npm install && npm start",

"compile:scss": "node-sass src/assets/scss/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss src/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.css",

"minify:scss": "node-sass src/assets/scss/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss src/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.min.css --output-style compressed",

"map:scss": "node-sass src/assets/scss/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.scss src/assets/css/light-bootstrap-dashboard-react.css --source-map true",

"build:scss": "npm run compile:scss && npm run minify:scss && npm run map:scss"

},

## Error:

## Using Nixpacks

Nixpacks build failed

If someone could help me, so as not to leave the railway.

The Heroku buildpacks are finally leaving Railway forever on Novermber 14th.

Moving From Heroku to Railway

I really appreciate any help, I'm new to this type of development

Answer (score 0):

In railway settings>general>root directory> name of the directory where you do mpn start
&&
package.json>"scripts">"start": "nodemon src/app.js"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).